# Split-Apply-Combine to aggregate rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I am trying to run split-apply-combine on the following pandas dataframe. I want to to show, for each unique customer code, a count of rows where col1 value is less than or equal to 0, and a count of rows where col1 value is more than 0.

So this table:

```
    cust_code   col1    col2
0   113231413   -10     2795.19 
1   113231413   20      1485.76 
2   113231413   25      6201.18 
3   113231413   -25     1502.40 
4   526242422   -23     6470.12 
5   526242422   0       14011.28    
6   414314134   0       12426.78    
7   414314134   26      12104.77
```

Becomes:

```
           cust_code    count1 count2   
0          113231413      2      2      
1          526242422      2      0      
2          414314134      1      1
```

I know the first step is to use groupby, but I am unsure of what to do next:

```
count = df.groupby('cust_code')['cust_code'].count()
```

Comment: Your expected result does not make sense given your problem statement.  For example, "count of rows where col2 value is more than 0".  For cust_code 113231413, that should be 4, not 2 per the expected result.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I rephrased the question. I want count2 to be a count of rows whose col1 value (not col2 value) is more than 0, grouped by cust_code.

Answer (score 1):

For pandas >= 0.25 Try:

```
df.groupby('cust_code')['col1'].agg(count1=(lambda s: s.loc[s <= 0].count()), 
                                    count2=(lambda s: s.loc[s > 0].count())).reset_index()

   cust_code  count1  count2
0  113231413       2       2
1  414314134       1       1
2  526242422       2       0
```

---

Or for older pandas version:

```
df1 = df.groupby('cust_code').agg(
          {'col1': [lambda s: s.loc[s <= 0].count(),
                    lambda s: s.loc[s > 0].count()]
          }
      ).reset_index()
df1.columns=['cust_code','count1','count2']
df1
   cust_code  count1  count2
0  113231413       2       2
1  414314134       1       1
2  526242422       2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, never filter per groups, because slow if many groups. Better is create new columns filled by masks converted to integers and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(col1=df['col1'].le(0).astype(int),
               col2=df['col1'].gt(0).astype(int))
        .groupby('cust_code',sort=False)[['col1','col2']]
        .sum())
print   (df)1
           col1  col2
cust_code            
113231413     2     2
526242422     2     0
414314134     1     1
```